# string replacement in multiple files in a bat file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Iam new to batch processing and developed a piece of code which takes a folder and files inside that folder(folder(911) is placed on my desktop) and replaces a string (inside all the files in that folder)to another string,if found.(These two strings should be taken from command prompt user input).Also I want to redirect the changed files inside the folder to some folder with all the changed files or atleast save them in the original file rewriting the old string.How?

I know this is simple but my code is not working.Iam totally new.Please enlighten and help me.

```
@ECHO OFF
pause
pushd %cd%
set folder="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
pause
cd %folder%
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /D %%g IN (???) DO (
    set checkpath="%cd%\%%g\991"
    if exist !checkpath! (
        for /F %%L in ('%%g\991\*.*') do (
            SET "Code=%%L"
            SET /p branchCode=Enter a Branch Code:
            SET /p newBranchCode=Enter New Branch Code:
            SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
            ECHO !Code:branchCode=newBranchCode!
            ENDLOCAL
            pause
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: If you explain what you actually need to do, with examples, it would be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I just wanted to replace a user input string with another user input string taken from multiple files within a folder and save it if possible,or redirect the changes to the other set of files.

Comment: I want to replace one branch code with the other,to be precise.

Comment: Need way more information and examples. We don't know your branch codes, or what information is in the files. Suppose you want to replace `123` with `456` - well, all fine and good, but how is any program supposed to distinguish a branc code from say a sales figure of `5,123` units or a sales amount of `$2,123.65` or a street address of `123 Brown St.`? surely you don't want to make those substitutions arbitrarily?

Answer (score 0):

This will behave as outlined by @Magoo in the comments - the term will be found and replaced wherever it is located. `Note` that the `%branchcode%` term is a regular expression and some types of characters will need special handling.  Alphanumerics will be fine.

It uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder you are processing files in, or in a folder that is on the path, or specify the full path to repl.bat

```
@echo off
pushd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\source folder"

SET /p "branchCode=Enter a Branch Code: "
SET /p "newBranchCode=Enter New Branch Code: "
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
type "%%a" | repl "%branchcode%" "%newbranchcode%" > "%%~na-edited%%~xa"
)
popd
```

Comment: Can you please go through my code and suggest some changes<https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yeBigU5OBsG0FeeaASgoCTcosV8WeBzHNlQshQmd4Ac/edit?usp=sharing>?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem These two strings should be taken from command prompt user input
SET /p branchCode=Enter a Branch Code:
SET /p newBranchCode=Enter New Branch Code:

rem  takes a folder and files inside that folder(folder(911)
set "folder=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\911"
cd %folder%

rem inside all the files in that folder
for %%a in (*.*) do (
   (for /F "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
      set "line=%%b"
      rem replaces a string to another string,if found
      echo !line:%branchCode%=%newBranchCode%!
   rem redirect the changed files inside the folder to some folder
   )) > "%folder%\someFolder\%%a"
)
```

This Batch file have some details that should be fixed; however, we must know first if this is what you want...

Comment: Thanks for your help Aacini!What you have modified is exactly what I want but this code is not working some how...it is failing in the for loop.However I have placed my .bat file on my desktop where 911 is residing  and checked back whether your code is working or not.NO :(.

Comment: :This is my improvised code.Please tell me where I need to edit this: [Script.bat] (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yeBigU5OBsG0FeeaASgoCTcosV8WeBzHNlQshQmd4Ac/edit?usp=sharing)